# Solving a complex equation including |conj(z)|

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find the solutions for this equation: $z^2-|\bar z-3|-3=0$.

How can I manage that modulus? Do I need to split the equation into two different cases?

Comment: First of all, $z^2$ must be real, right?

Comment: When you say "Splitting the equation into **two** different cases", you are thinking as if you were working with real quantities where $|a|=\pm a$ but this is not at all the case here. Follow the advice of Tbw : write your equation $|\overline{z}-3|=3-z^2$ where the left hand side is real, therefore the right handside is real also, which means that its imaginary part is $0$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I'm really bad at solving complex equations but I think I managed to understand thanks to all of your advices

Comment: It doesn't matter much here for the resolution, but note that $|z|=|\bar z|$ and the real shift changes nothing i.e $|z-3|=|\bar z-3|$ and possibly the equation is less frightening now without $\bar z$ appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Set $z=x+iy$, where $x,y\in\mathbb R$. Plugging it into the equation gives
$$
(x+yi)^2-|x-iy-3|-3=0
$$
that is
$$
2xyi=3+\sqrt{(x-3)^2+y^2}+y^2-x^2
$$
Since the right-hand side is real, it follows that $2xy=0$, so either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

If $x=0$, then we get the equation
$$
0=3+\sqrt{9+y^2}+y^2
$$
which is not solvable with real $y$.

If $y=0$, then we get the equation
$$
0=3+\sqrt{(x-3)^2}-x^2
$$
that is
$$
x^2-3=|x-3|
$$
Therefore, either $x=2$ or $x=-3$. Thus, the solutions of the equation are $z=2+0i=2$ and $z=-3+0i=-3$.